# what is the complexity of an algorithim who runs in $\sum1/(i^2)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

i am trieng to find an easier way to write the following :
f1=$\sum1/(i^2)$ (the sum from1 to n)because i want to check if it's f1=O(f2)
when$f2=(log(n^{100}))-log(n^{99}))$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question using mathjax so we can read it. Be sure to tell us where $n$ appears in the formula for f1. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: i edited the question